# ckeditor works fine when create post but missing when edit post

Tags: php, laravel, ckeditor

In the **app.blade.php** file I have added:

```
<script src="../vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'article-ckeditor' );
</script>
```

And then in the **create.blade.php** file:

```
{{Form::textarea('body','',['id'=>'article-ckeditor',
                            'class'=>'form-control',
                            'placeholder'=>'Body Text'])
}}
```

In the **edit.blade.php** file:

```
{{Form::textarea('body', $post->body,['id'=> 'article-ckeditor',
                                      'class'=>'form-control',
                                      'placeholder'=>'Body Text'])
}}
```

CKeditor shows on create a page but missing on the edit page.

My question is, what else I must write down in the Laravel, that the CKeditor will be visible on edit page?

Comment: check the console to see if there is a javascript error on Edit page or not

Comment: it looks like there is no error

Comment: after page load run this command on the console in Edit page:
CKEDITOR.replace( 'article-ckeditor' );
see what happened next.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, just in case you still have the issue, check out:

https://artisansweb.net/install-use-ckeditor-laravel/

Also make sure the script with string interpolation `{{asset}}` in `app.blade.php` points to the correct path. Mine had to jump out of the folder to vendor `(../vendor)`. Yours could be different.

Note that the next script has `CKEDITOR.replace( 'summary-ckeditor' );` and **not** `CKEDITOR.replace( article-ckeditor' );` Most important ensure your `id` in both `edit.blade.php` and `create.blade.php` points to `summary-ckeditor` and not `article-ckeditor`.